# How to acces the the django ManyToMany Field in django Template

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have set of attributes in my Models from which one of the attribute is of Type ManyToMany Field. I am able to access all the Attributes in Template instead one which is ManyToMany Field.

I have tried following in my template

```
{% for post in all_posts %}
{{ post.likes }}
{% endfor %}
```

models.py

```
class Posts(models.Model):
title = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=False)
content = models.CharField(max_length=15000,
                           help_text="Write Your thought here...")
creation_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, editable=False)
likes = models.ManyToManyField(User, blank=True, related_name='likes')
```

views.py

```
def home(request):
    template = loader.get_template('home.html')
    all_posts = Posts.objects.all()
     context = {
         'all_posts': all_posts,
     }
     return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))
```

When i Use `{{ post.likes }}` what renders on page is auth.User.None

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to traverse over all the likes for the selected post

Try something like this:

```
{% for post in all_posts %}
    {% for like in post.likes.all %}
        {{ like }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```